# Is there a sample code in unix shell script to download a file from a shared folder in Windows?

Tags: linux, unix, sh

I am using a shell script that uses mailx to send an excel file stored in the server to some people.

The problem is, I have to use winscp to upload the file from windows to the linux server.

Perhaps there is a line of code I could use so I don't have to transfer the file manually to the server.

```
cd /home/guava/autoemail

datediff=1
datetoday=$(date +%Y%m%d)
foldername=$(date --date="${datetoday} -${datediff} day" +%Y%m%d)

''DEAR STACKOVERFLOW USER, I WANT TO PUT THE CODE THAT I ASK HERE IF THERE IS ANY''


cat /home/guava/autoemail/email_body.txt | mailx -s "AML_20M_DAILY_TRANSACTION_REPORT_GUAVA_$foldername" -a /home/guava/autoemail/DEALS_ENTERED_TODAY_ALL_2OM_UP_$foldername.xls bbsolpico@gmail.com
```

Comment: I want to insert the code that downloads the file from windows (if there is any) just before the code that emails it.

Comment: I need some code similar to the way WinSCP transfers files to the server but the difference is, I'm on a linux perspective.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. If the remote shared folder is exposed as a mount point, the same `scp` command should work. If it's only visible as a Windows share, try `smbclient`.